# Delphi Berlin 10.1 IXMLDOCUMENT root node prefix

Tags: xml, delphi, xmldocument

I am trying to create XML in Delphi Berlin 10.1
and I need to obtain a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica versione="FPA12" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2 http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.2/Schema_del_file_xml_FatturaPA_versione_1.2.xsd">
  <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
    <DatiTrasmissione>
      <IdTrasmittente>
        <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
        <IdCodice>01234567890</IdCodice>
      </IdTrasmittente>
      <ProgressivoInvio>00001</ProgressivoInvio>
      <FormatoTrasmissione>FPA12</FormatoTrasmissione>
      <CodiceDestinatario>AAAAAA</CodiceDestinatario>
    </DatiTrasmissione>
...
```

and I wrote this procedure

```
    procedure Tfattura2_new_form.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    Var
      XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
      RootNode, CurNode, header[...]: IXMLNODE;
    begin
      XML := NewXMLDocument;
      XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
      XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent]; 
      RootNode := XML.AddChild('FatturaElettronica');
      RootNode.Attributes['versione']:='FPA12';
      RootNode.DeclareNamespace('ds','http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#');
      RootNode.DeclareNamespace('p','http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2');
      RootNode.DeclareNamespace('xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
   [...]
    
      header := RootNode.AddChild('FatturaElettronicaHeader');
      DatiTrasmissione := header.AddChild('DatiTrasmissione');
    
      IdTrasmittente :=  DatiTrasmissione.AddChild('IdTrasmittente');
          [...]
    XMl.SaveToFile('C:\file.xml');
end;
```

now the problemi is that I need to have prefix p in root node (p:FatturaElettronica... )
but if I don't know how:
if I set

```
RootNode := XML.AddChild('p:FatturaElettronica');
```

in xml file I have prefix p: in every tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica versione="FPA12" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2 http://www.fatturapa.gov.it/export/fatturazione/sdi/fatturapa/v1.2/Schema_del_file_xml_FatturaPA_versione_1.2.xsd">
  <p:FatturaElettronicaHeader>
    <p:DatiTrasmissione>
      <p:IdTrasmittente>
        <p:IdPaese>IT</p:IdPaese>
        <p:IdCodice>09876543211</p:IdCodice>
      </p:IdTrasmittente>
      <p:ProgressivoInvio>23</p:ProgressivoInvio>
      <p:FormatoTrasmissione>FPR12</p:FormatoTrasmissione>
      <p:CodiceDestinatario>0000000</p:CodiceDestinatario>
    </p:DatiTrasmissione>
```

How I can fix it?
Thankyou.

Comment: Ho avuto lo stesso problema.
Risolto.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short, you can't do this with `IXMLNode.AddChild()` alone.

When you use `AddChild()` to add a new child element, and you do not explicitly specify a namespace, the new child inherits the namespace of its parent element, and if the parent has a namespace prefix then that prefix gets inherited as well.  This is hard-coded behavior in `AddChild()`, you can't change it.  This is why you see the `p:` prefix on all of the child nodes.

If you use the overloaded `AddChild()` that takes a namespace as input, you can omit the prefix on the child element, and the parent's prefix will not be inherited.  However, the new child element will have its own `xmlns` declaration, even if the namespace is the same as the parent's namespace:

```pascal
header := RootNode.AddChild('FatturaElettronicaHeader', 'http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2');
```

Result:

```xml
<FatturaElettronicaHeader xmlns="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2">
```

You can't change this behavior, either.

But, there is a workaround - create the child node separately without any parent element or namespace, and then insert it as-is into the parent element, eg:

```pascal
//header := RootNode.AddChild('FatturaElettronicaHeader');
header := XML.CreateElement('FatturaElettronicaHeader', '');
RootNode.ChildNodes.Add(header);
```

Then you can use `AddChild()` for subsequent child elements, and they will inherit the non-existent namespace of the `FatturaElettronicaHeader` element, eg:

```pascal
XML := NewXMLDocument;
XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];

RootNode := XML.AddChild('p:FatturaElettronica', 'http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2');
RootNode.Attributes['versione']:='FPA12';
RootNode.DeclareNamespace('ds','http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#');
RootNode.DeclareNamespace('p','http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2');
RootNode.DeclareNamespace('xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

//header := RootNode.AddChild('FatturaElettronicaHeader');
header := XML.CreateElement('FatturaElettronicaHeader', '');
RootNode.ChildNodes.Add(header);

DatiTrasmissione := header.AddChild('DatiTrasmissione');
IdTrasmittente := DatiTrasmissione.AddChild('IdTrasmittente');

IdTrasmittente.AddChild('IdPaese').Text := 'IT';
IdTrasmittente.AddChild('IdCodice').Text := '01234567890';

DatiTrasmissione.AddChild('ProgressivoInvio').Text := '00001';
DatiTrasmissione.AddChild('FormatoTrasmissione').Text := 'FPA12';
DatiTrasmissione.AddChild('CodiceDestinatario').Text := 'AAAAAA';

XML.SaveToFile('C:\file.xml');
```

Result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:FatturaElettronica versione="FPA12" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <FatturaElettronicaHeader>
    <DatiTrasmissione>
      <IdTrasmittente>
        <IdPaese>IT</IdPaese>
        <IdCodice>01234567890</IdCodice>
      </IdTrasmittente>
      <ProgressivoInvio>00001</ProgressivoInvio>
      <FormatoTrasmissione>FPA12</FormatoTrasmissione>
      <CodiceDestinatario>AAAAAA</CodiceDestinatario>
    </DatiTrasmissione>
  </FatturaElettronicaHeader>
</p:FatturaElettronica>
```

Comment: very good answer . i had same problem. 
thanks a lot !
regards
Stefano

Comment: Thanks! I´ve been having this problem too. Now it´s ok!